# Property of Closure and the limit point

Tags: general-topology

Definitions:

$A'$ is the set of all accumulation or limit points.

$\bar{A} = A \cup A'$ - this is known as the closure of $A$.

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. A point $p\in\mathbb{R}$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if and only if every open set $G$ containing $p$ contains a point of $A$ different from $p$.

**Prove** or **disprove**: $(\overline{A\bigcup B}) = \overline{A}\bigcup \overline{B}$

proof: let $p\in (\overline{A\bigcup B})$ be an accumulation of the union, then there exists some open set $S_{p}$ containing $p$ which also contains a point of $(\overline{A\bigcup B})$ different from $p$. Let's call this point $q$, where $p\neq q$ such that $q\in S_{p} \subset (\overline{A\bigcup B})$. Further let's suppose that p is not an accumulation point of $A$ nor of $B$. Then this contradicts $p\in (\overline{A\bigcup B})$, therefore $(\overline{A\bigcup B}) = \overline{A}\bigcup \overline{B}$.

I am not sure if I am correct , if anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you define $q$, $q$ should be in $A\cup B$, not $\overline{A\cup B}$.  You should place all your assumptions at the beginning, i.e., that $p$ is an accumulation point of the union and that $p$ is not an accumulation point of $A$ and not an accumulation point of $B$.  Also, what is your contradiction?  Make sure that your contradiction is clear and obvious.  Finally, this looks like only one side of a set equality proof.  You need to check the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one direction.  We show that $\overline{A\cup B}\subseteq \overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$.

Let $x\in \overline{A\cup B}$.  Then $x\in A\cup B$ or $x$ is an accumulation point of $A\cup B$.  We proceed by cases.

Assume first that $x\in A\cup B$, then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$.  If $x\in A$, then $x\in\overline{A}$ so $x\in\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$.  If $x\in B$, then $x\in\overline{B}$, so $x\in\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$.  Therefore, $x\in\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$.

Now, assume $x$ is an accumulation point of $A\cup B$, but $x\not\in A\cup B$.  Assume, for contradiction, that $x$ is not an accumulation point of $A$ and not an accumulation point of $B$.  Then, there are open sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ containing $x$ such that $S_1\cap A=\emptyset$ and $S_2\cap B=\emptyset$ (these are empty sets because the intersection can only be $x$ and $x\not\in A\cup B$).

Let $S=S_1\cap S_2$.  This is an open set containing $x$ and $S\cap A=\emptyset=S\cap B$.  Therefore, $S\cap (A\cup B)=\{x\}$, so $x$ is not an accumulation point of $A\cup B$, a contradiction.

Comment: What would I have to show in the other directions that essentially that $\overline{A}\bigcup \overline{B}\subset (\overline{A\bigcup B})$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you must show.  Start with an element of the LHS and prove that it's in the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

We have $(\overline{A\bigcup B}) = ({A}\bigcup{B})\bigcup({A}\bigcup{B})'$, and also $\bar{A}\bigcup \bar{B} = {A}\bigcup{A'}\bigcup{B}\bigcup{B'}={A}\bigcup{B}\bigcup{A'}\bigcup{B'}=({A}\bigcup{B})\bigcup{A'}\bigcup{B'}$, so the question boils down to proving $({A}\bigcup{B})'={A'}\bigcup{B'}$. Which is provable by noticing that if $x \in A'$ or $x \in B'$ or $x$ is in both, then it is certainly in $({A}\bigcup{B})'$, and vice versa.